# Flutter Firestore sets data before page is loaded

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add my data in a textformfield which then saves to firestore, this includes the documentID. The data comes back as null or "" for some reason.
Below is my code:

```
  final barcode = TextEditingController();
  final price = TextEditingController();
  final stock = TextEditingController();
  final color = TextEditingController();
  addData() {
    Map<String, dynamic> theData = {
      "Color" : color.text,
      "Price" : price.text,
      "Stock" : stock.text,
    };
    CollectionReference collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("products");
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("products").doc(barcode.text).set(theData);
    collectionReference.add(theData);

  }
```

I have tried making it async but still nothing, I want the data to be set when I click the done button which has a onpressed method calling the addData.

This is my data in firestore when I only set the data and not the ID:
[image]

Comment: Can you share the code where you call addData() method?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use await

```
    addData() async { // ASYNC HERE
    Map<String, dynamic> theData = {
      "Color" : color.text,
      "Price" : price.text,
      "Stock" : stock.text,
    };
    CollectionReference collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("products");
    await collectionReference.doc(barcode.text).set(theData, merge:true); // AWAIT HERE
```

or

```
CollectionReference collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("products");
        await collectionReference.doc(barcode.text).updateData(theData); // AWAIT HERE
  }
```

Also not sure why you both set and add theData? Use `updateData()` or `set()` with `merge:true`. The document will be created either way

Comment: I get the folllowing error, maybe I have to put it in a future? : Expected a value ot type '(() => void)?', but got one of type '+Future<dynamic>'